# MySQL Select statement ---show all where this unless this ---not quite sure how to do that

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a SQL query that will select everything shown...but I have a condition where the total hours !=0. This works but I must add one more condition that would exclude the condition of total hours !=0.

I basically need the query to look like: AND project_timecard_task_days.total_hours != 0 UNLESS task.type ="Fixed Rate"

So, the "unless" part of the statement is the issue. Any help will be much appreciated!

```
SELECT project_timecard_tasks.task_id, 
       project_timecard_tasks.datetime, 
       project_timecard_tasks.total_hours, 
       project_timecard_tasks.user_id, 
       project_timecard_tasks.project_id, 
       users.user_id, 
       users.firstname, 
       users.lastname, 
       users.billingrate, 
       tasks.id, 
       tasks.taskname, 
       tasks.billingoption, 
       tasks.fixedrate, 
       tasks.rate_schedule_id, 
       hourlyrates.rate_schedule_id, 
       hourlyrates.hourlyrate, 
       project_timecard_tasks.project_task_id, 
       project_timecard_task_days.project_task_id, 
       project_timecard_task_days.project_task_day_id, 
       project_timecard_task_days.total_hours, 
       project_timecard_task_days.comments, 
       project_timecard_task_days.invoiced 
FROM   project_timecard_tasks 
       JOIN users 
         ON project_timecard_tasks.user_id = users.user_id 
       JOIN tasks 
         ON project_timecard_tasks.task_id = tasks.id 
       JOIN project_timecard_task_days 
         ON project_timecard_tasks.project_task_id = 
            project_timecard_task_days.project_task_id 
       JOIN hourlyrates 
         ON project_timecard_tasks.billing_code_id = hourlyrates.hourly_rate_id 
WHERE  project_timecard_tasks.project_id = '$jobNumber' 
       AND project_timecard_task_days.total_hours != 0 
       AND project_timecard_task_days.invoiced != 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
...AND (project_timecard_task_days.total_hours != 0 OR task.type ="Fixed Rate")...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `OR`:

```
WHERE
(
  project_timecard_tasks.project_id = '$jobNumber' 
  AND 
  project_timecard_task_days.total_hours != 0 
  AND 
  project_timecard_task_days.invoiced != 1 
)
OR
  task.type ="Fixed Rate"
```

or perhaps (depending on how you want your conditions):

```
WHERE
  project_timecard_tasks.project_id = '$jobNumber' 
  AND 
  project_timecard_task_days.invoiced != 1 
  AND 
  (
    project_timecard_task_days.total_hours != 0
    OR
    task.type ="Fixed Rate"
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `OR` statement.

```
...
AND (project_timecard_task_days.total_hours != 0 OR task.type = "Fixed Rate")
AND...
```